# Search Tool: Generate URL from Source File + Line (Visual Studio)

Tags: github, bitbucket-server, visual-studio-sdk

I'll took some time to find a tool (without success) that helps to easily switch from Visual Studio editor to the web frontend of our (git) code repository.

**The idea in mind is**: In a (chat) discussion about some coding sometime its useful to refer to a line of code. Currently one/I am writing e.g.

> see repo_path/Dragable.cpp:29

... or bit better/easier/faster to follow is sending the link to our repo web frontend e.g.

> see http://192.168.2.50:7990/projects/GST/repos/gst/browse/src/Client/ClientGUI/Dragable.cpp#29

*In my case the is a atlassian-stash based URL because we are using atlassian-stash as git repo / web frontend. But I think this problem is valid for nearly any code repo with a web frontend e.g. github*

> *(same example but github)*
>
> *https://github.com/google/protobuf/blob/master/src/google/protobuf/arenastring.h#L88*

**Now the question:**
Typically I am browsing through the code while discussing things using my favorite IDE (this is in our team typically visual studio). I am searching for a tool that allows to generate a URL (like above) from the current cursor position (where a relative path from the current source file + the line is placed into an URL stub).

I still did not find an adequate tool (or plugin) that has this functionality in it (maybe as side functionality). Before starting building a custom VS Extension, I would like to ask if maybe somebody else was faced to the same issue, solved it already with an existing tool or can suggest a tool/workflow for this?